# Add time to current date in javascript or type script

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

i am trying to add a time to current date.

example:

i have this time : `05:17 am`

i want to add this time current date by replace current time by this time.

if current date and time is : `10-09-2021 11:30 am`

i want to add current date and replace time by my specific time => output for example above: `10-09-2021 05:17 am`

i am trying:

```
var time = this.timeInput;
new Date().getTime() + convertTimeToInt(time);

// in this case we add current time to my input time, i don't want this.
```

`convertTimeToInt()` is a method that convert time to int.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do

```
let time = '05:17 pm';
let splittedTime = time.split(' ');
let [hours, minutes] = splittedTime[0].split(':');
let isAm = splittedTime[1] === 'am'; // in europe we don't use am, the hours goes from 0 to 24

var date = new Date(); // now
console.log('before ' + date); 

let hourToAdd = 0;
if(+hours === 12) {
    if(isAm) {
        hourToAdd = - 12; // at midnight we dont add +12 nor +0, we want 12am to be 0 hours
    } else {
        hourToAdd = 0;
    }
} else {
    hourToAdd = isAm ? 0 : 12;
}

// use setHours to set time
date.setHours(+hours + hourToAdd, +minutes, 0, 0); 
console.log('after ' + date);
```

Output:

```
let time = '12:17 pm';
[LOG]: "before Fri Sep 10 2021 14:37:07 GMT+0200
[LOG]: "after Fri Sep 10 2021 12:17:00 GMT+0200

let time = '12:17 am';
[LOG]: "before Fri Sep 10 2021 14:37:27 GMT+0200
[LOG]: "after Fri Sep 10 2021 00:17:00 GMT+0200

let time = '05:17 am';
[LOG]: "before Fri Sep 10 2021 14:37:45 GMT+0200
[LOG]: "after Fri Sep 10 2021 05:17:00 GMT+0200

let time = '05:17 pm';
[LOG]: "before Fri Sep 10 2021 14:38:21 GMT+0200
[LOG]: "after Fri Sep 10 2021 17:17:00 GMT+0200
```

**UPDATE: without am/pm, you can use**

```
let time = '05:17';
let [hours, minutes] = time.split(':');
var date = new Date(); // now
console.log('before ' + date); 
date.setHours(+hours, +minutes, 0, 0); // set hours/minute
console.log('after ' + date);
```

Output:

```
[LOG]: "before Fri Sep 10 2021 11:03:07 GMT+0200 
[LOG]: "after Fri Sep 10 2021 05:17:00 GMT+0200
```

Comment: oh i am sorry bro, i am using time from 0 to 24 not am and pm :( .
how to refactor this code? @Pilpo

Comment: I updated my answer according to your comment :)

Comment: `isAm ? +hours : +hours + 12` will fail for 12 am and 12 pm, it should be `hours % 12 + isAm ? 0 : 12` where *isAm* can be `let isAm = /am/i.test(time);`.

Comment: @RobG  I don't agree with you for the case `12 am`, because if it's `12:00 am`, we want it to be noon, so `12` is good. But you are right, there was a missing case for 12pm, we want it to be at midnight not +24hours after. I've updated my answer thanks to you! Thanks

Comment: 12 am is typically midnight, not noon, so should convert to 0, not 12. On the other hand, 12 pm is typically noon, but the above code will convert it to 24, which is midnight at the end of the day so convert to 0 and increment the date.

Comment: Oh my mistake, thanks for the clarification! Answer updated :)

Comment: @Pilpo—no problem, 12 am and 12 pm are confusing, I use noon and midnight instead. :-)